# How to call an external function in PHP

Tags: php, function

I want to call an external function in PHP from inside of a class function, but it does not work.

I've tried with include and require at various locations of the PHP class file, but without success.

The following function is located in the file Amd.php

```
<?php

function AmdGetFirstName($sUsername){
    $oUserModel = new UserCoreModel;
    $iProfileId = $oUserModel->getId(null, $sUsername);
    $sFirstName = $oUserModel->getFirstName($iProfileId);
    unset($oUserModel);
    return $sFirstName;
}
```

Now I want to call this function from a class function with the following code:

```
<?php

require_once PATH_ROOT . '/Amd.php';

class Design
{
    public function getProfileLink($sUsername)
    {
        $sFirstName = AmdGetFirstName($sUsername);

        $sHtml = '<a href="';
        $sHtml .= (new UserCore)->getProfileLink($sUsername);
        $sHtml .= '" title="' . t("%0%'s profile", $sFirstName) . '">'; 
        $sHtml .= $sFirstName . '</a>';

        echo $sHtml;
    }
}
```

When I debug the code the function `AmdGetFirstName` is not called from within the public function `getProfileLink`.
If I call the same function in the index.php file with the same require_once statement it works very well.
The difference what I can see is that in index.php the function is not called within another function or class function.
I also tried to locate the require_once statement inside of the class function with the same result.

Comment: You say: "When I debug the code the function AmdGetFirstName is not called from within the public function getProfileLink". How do you know? Do you get an error? Which one? No error? What HTML is returned?

Comment: my best guess: you're probably _NOT_ showing us a vital part of Amd.php which creates a namespace, and your problem is probably that you're not using that namespace in your call.

Comment: You are using the constant: `PATH_ROOT` in the require statement. It needs to be defined in order to locate the Amd.php file. One option is that you remove the constant and give absolute path to Amd.php

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, I use Netbeans to debug. The program execution stopped at the breakpoint before the function call. With Step In I could not reach the function.

Comment: @hanshenrik you guess was correct. I used another file as template and forgot to remove the namespace. Thanks a lot! Now it works.

Comment: Thanks @NadirLatif. The constant was already initialized. I did not show this program part. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

class Design
{
    public function getProfileLink($sUsername)
    {
        require_once PATH_ROOT . '/Amd.php';

        $sFirstName = AmdGetFirstName($sUsername);

        $sHtml = '<a href="';
        $sHtml .= (new UserCore)->getProfileLink($sUsername);
        $sHtml .= '" title="' . t("%0%'s profile", $sFirstName) . '">'; 
        $sHtml .= $sFirstName . '</a>';

        echo $sHtml;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but in my case the problem was an incorrect  namespace setting. After correcting the namespace it even worked with the required statement outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to include the Amd.php with include on using dirname(**FILE**) like bellow:

```
include (dirname(__FILE__)."/Amd.php")
```

Comment: Ok, will check this function out, but the path was not the reason.
The file could be included successfully.